# Re-structuring CVS repositories and retaining history

Tags: repository, cvs, history

Currently, we have the following in our CVS Repository :

```
Module1
  |
  |
  +-----A
  |
  +-----B
```

We want o restructure this module such that the sub directories A and B appears as high level modules. What I could do is to check Module1 out and then pull A and B out and then do a fresh `cvs add` for A and B individually, thus making them new cvs modules. But I am sure if I do this, I am going to lose the history as well as I would have to remove all internal CVS folders under A and B.

Q1: So is there a way to restructure this and retain the history?

What I essentially am trying to do is to filter out access between A and B. 
So -

Q2: Is there a way to set up security so that certain users can check out Module1/A only and not Module1/B ? and vice-versa?

Comment: OK. So looks to me that if I have file system permissions, I could just to the CVS server, goto cvs root and re-structure the directories. The directories moved right under cvsroot will be available for check out as new modules.  Does anyone see any issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Q1: So is there a way to restructure this and retain the history?`

Like you wrote in your comment, if you have sys privs you can `mv` modules around the repository and keep the history of all the files below A and B but in doing so, you lose the history that /A used to be Module1/A and /B used to be in Module1/B (not to mention build scripts probably break now).  `Subversion` resolves this for you by offering the `move` (or rename) command which remembers the move/rename history of a module.

`Q2: Is there a way to set up security so that certain users can check out Module1/A only and not Module1/B ? and vice-versa?`

There sure is, used group permissions.  From this page,
http://www.linux.ie/articles/tutorials/managingaccesswithcvs.php
Here's the snip I'm referring to in case that page ever goes away

> **To every module its group**
>
> We have seen earlier how creating a
>   cvsusers group helped with the
>   coordination of the work of several
>   developers. We can extend this
>   approach to permit directory level
>   check-in restrictions.
>
> In our example, let's say that the
>   module "cujo" is to be r/w for jack
>   and john, and the module "carrie" is
>   r/w for john and jill. We will create
>   two groups, g_cujo and g_carrie, and
>   add the appropriate users to each - in
>   /etc/group we add

```
g_cujo:x:3200:john,jack
g_carrie:x:3201:john,jill>
```

> Now in the repository (as root), run

```
find $CVSROOT/cujo -exec chgrp g_cujo {} \;
find $CVSROOT/carrie -exec chgrp g_carrie {} \;
```

> ensuring, as before, that all
>   directories have the gid bit set.
>
> Now if we have a look in the
>   repository...

```
   john@bolsh:~/cvs$ ls -l 
   total 16
   drwxrwsr-x    3 john     cvsadmin     4096 Dec 28 19:42 CVSROOT
   drwxrwsr-x    2 john     g_carrie     4096 Dec 28 19:35 carrie
   drwxrwsr-x    2 john     g_cujo       4096 Dec 28 19:40 cujo
```

> and if Jack tries to commit a change
>   to carrie...

```
   jack@bolsh:~/carrie$ cvs update
   cvs server: Updating .
   M test
   jack@bolsh:~/carrie$ cvs commit -m "test"
   cvs commit: Examining .
   Checking in test;
   /home/john/cvs/carrie/test,v  <--  test
   new revision: 1.2; previous revision: 1.1
   cvs [server aborted]: could not open lock file
   `/home/john/cvs/carrie/,test,': Permission denied
   jack@bolsh:~/carrie$
```

> But in cujo, there is no problem.

```
   jack@bolsh:~/cujo$ cvs update
   cvs server: Updating .
   M test
   jack@bolsh:~/cujo$ cvs commit -m "Updating test"
   cvs commit: Examining .
   Checking in test;
   /home/john/cvs/cujo/test,v  <--  test
   new revision: 1.2; previous revision: 1.1
   done
   jack@bolsh:~/cujo$
```

> The procedure for adding a user is now
>   a little more complicated that it
>   might be. To create a new CVS user, we
>   have to create a system user, add them
>   to the groups corresponding to the
>   modules they may write to, and (if
>   you're using a pserver method)
>   generate a password for them, and add
>   an entry to CVSROOT/passwd.
>
> To add a project, we need to create a
>   group, import the sources, change the
>   groups on all the files in the
>   repository and make sure the set gid
>   on execution bit is set on all
>   directories inside the module, and add
>   the relevant users to the group.
>
> There is undoubtedly more
>   administration needed to do all this
>   than when we jab people with a pointy
>   stick. In that method, we never have
>   to add a system user or a group or
>   change the groups on directories - all
>   that is taken care of once we set up
>   the repository. This means that an
>   unpriveleged user can be the CVS admin
>   without ever having root priveleges on
>   the machine.

Comment: +1 and accepted! Thanks for going in great lengths explaining this